# Flutter Updated Listview from FCM Push Notifications?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

So far I am able to retrieve a single push notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging and display it on the screen. But I'd like to save all push notifications as a listview. So each time a new push notification is received, the listview is rebuilt and updated with the latest push notification at the top. Ideally, the user should be able to scroll back and see all the push notifications they've ever received.

Is this possible? Here's the code for displaying a single notification;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fcm_config/fcm_config.dart';

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
    RemoteMessage _notification) async {

  String title = _notification.data["title_key"];
  String body = _notification.data["body_key"];
  FCMConfig.displayNotification(title: title, body: body);
}

void main() async {   FCMConfig.init(onBackgroundMessage: _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler).then((value) {
    FCMConfig.subscribeToTopic("test_fcm_topic");
  });

  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with FCMNotificationMixin, FCMNotificationClickMixin {
  RemoteMessage _notification;
  final String serverToken ='myservertoken';

  @override
  void initState() {
      super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text("title"),
                subtitle: Text(_notification?.notification?.title ?? ""),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Body"),
                subtitle: Text(
                    _notification?.notification?.body ?? "No notification"),
              ),
              if (_notification != null)
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("data"),
                  subtitle: Text(_notification?.data?.toString() ?? ""),
                )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void onNotify(RemoteMessage notification) {
    _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(notification);
    setState(() {
      _notification = notification;
    });
  }

  @override
  void onClick(RemoteMessage notification) {
    setState(() {
      _notification = notification;
    });
    print(
        "Notification clicked with title: ${notification.notification.title} && body: ${notification.notification.body}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save all of your notification on the [database](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) but I think the best way is you must save all of your notification on a server

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Do you know how I can get any new notifications to trigger a rebuild of the list?

Comment: Yes, you can use state management in Flutter please refer to this link:
https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: How would I save the notifications on a server instead of a database? You mean as a JSON or text file?

Comment: I mean server created with node js and MongoDB

Comment: Im using MySQL. I guess I can push any new rows to FCM for updating the list and make the first query as a future when first opening the page. I think I can use Provider to update the list upon a new notification.

Comment: Yes you can do it

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to refresh list
use

```
List<RemoteMessage> _notifications=[];
```

and when any notification come

```
_notifications.insert(0,notification);
```

but if you need to save it for later time

in the latest version of fcm_config

```
fcm_config 3.0.0-nullsafety.1
```

you can get notification as json

```
_notification.toMap()
```

you can then save it in shared_prefernces or any other way
and you can parse it again

```
RemoteMessage.fromMap(...)
```

Comment: I'm getting a whole chain of errors with that fcm_config 3.0.0-nullsaftey.1 Because fcm_config >=3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on flutter_local_notifications ^5.0.0-nullsafety.0 and speakoholic depends on flutter_local_notifications ^4.0.1+1, fcm_config >=3.0.0-nullsafety.0 is forbidden.
So, because speakoholic depends on fcm_config ^3.0.0-nullsafety.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because speakoholic depends on fcm_config ^3.0.0-nullsafety.1, version solving failed.)

Comment: Upon upgrade I get an even more problems; Because no versions of firebase_cloud_messaging match >4.0.4+1 <5.0.0 and firebase_cloud_messaging 4.0.4+1 depends on platform ^2.0.0, firebase_cloud_messaging ^4.0.4+1 requires platform ^2.0.0.
And because flutter_local_notifications >=5.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on platform ^3.0.0, firebase_cloud_messaging ^4.0.4+1 is incompatible with flutter_local_notifications >=5.0.0-nullsafety.0.
So, because speakoholic depends on both flutter_local_notifications ^5.0.0-nullsafety.0 and firebase_cloud_messaging ^4.0.4+1, version solving failed.
pub get failed

Comment: So its seems this newest FCM_config is incompatible with flutter_local_notifications.

Comment: The most recent FCM_config version I can use is ^2.0.0-dev.18. Does  _notification.toMap() work with this version?

Comment: fcm_ onfig is now null safety and must depend on null safety packages firbase_messaging:9.0.0 and flutter_local_notifications :5

Comment: So you have to use some thing like dependency_ovverides if you can not to update your packages to null safety